# add cash on delivery fee to the PDF invoice magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, create-invoice

I have enabled Cash on Delivery with a new extension. but the Fee doesn't show on the PDF invoice.

how can I make it shown on it?
Magento 1.9

I have added new extension for the COD because the default COD from Magento doesn't have fee.

Answer (score 0):

To display COD fee you need to add below tag in your module `config.xml` under   `<global>` tag

```
        <pdf>
            <totals>
                <custom_cashondelivery translate="title">
                    <title>Cash on Delivery fee</title>
                    <source_field>cod_fee</source_field>
                    <font_size>7</font_size>
                    <display_zero>0</display_zero>
                    <sort_order>450</sort_order>
                    <model>modulename_cashondelivery/sales_pdf_cod</model>
                </custom_cashondelivery>
            </totals>
        </pdf>
```

Where `<source_field>` is your custom attribute which you are saving COD fee value.

Now you need to create a `model` file for that which should extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default`

In this class

```
class Modulename_CashOnDelivery_Model_Sales_Pdf_Cod extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Total_Default
{

    public function getTotalsForDisplay()
    {
        $amount        = $this->getOrder()->formatPriceTxt($this->getAmount());
        $fontSize      = $this->getFontSize() ? $this->getFontSize() : 7;
        $helper        = Mage::helper('core');
            $totals = array(
                array(
                    'amount'    => $this->getAmountPrefix().$amount,
                    'label'     => $helper->__($this->getTitle()) . ':',
                    'font_size' => $fontSize
                )
            );
        return $totals;
    }
}
```

Also, rather than creating a new module for this you can use [this](https://github.com/PHOENIX-MEDIA/Magento-CashOnDelivery) free module which fulfills your requirements

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, this doesn't work :( I do exactly like that and also use the module you sent and nothing work 

this is what I add to config.xml http://prntscr.com/i06t2h

Comment: Please Install this module, It works without any problem I am using this module since long time for my client @muzramn

Comment: I do install it but the fee doesn't show on the PDF invoice. it's calculated right but it isn't shown to the customer.